# Is there any way to create a static const variable to a function pointer template parameter (or some equivalent)?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm not exactly sure how to word this question so I'll just use an example.

I have a class that takes some template parameters to call a member function of a class:

```
template<typename T, int V, void (T::*F)(int)>
struct CallFunction
{
    CallFunction()
    {
        T t;
        (t.*F)(V);
    }
};
```

And I have a class:

```
struct TestClass
{
    void TestFunc( int x ) { std::cout << "Value is: " << x << std::endl; }
};
```

I then invoke the CallFunction class:

```
int main()
{
    CallFunction<TestClass, 5, &TestClass::TestFunc> cf;
}
```

As expected this is printed:

```
Value is: 5
```

Now I decide that I want to add a layer between the template parameters and CallFunction.  Rather than provide each template parameter separately to CallFunction I want to create a "Description" class that provides the parameters.  So I try something like this:

```
template<typename D>
struct CallFunctionWithDescription
{
    CallFunctionWithDescription()
    {
        typename D::T t;
        (t.*typename D::F)(typename D::V);
    }
};

template<typename DT, int DV, void (DT::*DF)(int)>
struct Description
{
    typedef DT T;                         // OK
    static const int V = DV;              // OK
    static const void (T::*F)(int) = DF;  // VC++ error C2864!
};

struct TestClass
{
    void TestFunc( int x ) { std::cout << "Value is: " << x << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    typedef Description<TestClass, 5, &TestClass::TestFunc> TestClassDescription;
    CallFunctionWithDescription<TestClassDescription> cfd;
}
```

Not surprisingly this results in: "error C2864: 'Description::F' : only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class".

Is there any mechanism by which I can get a function pointer template parameter into CallFunctionWithDescription via the single type parameter D, or or am I required to pass the function pointer template argument to CallFunctionWithDescription directly?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you shouldn't use `typename` in this line: `(t.*typename D::F)(typename D::V);` because `F` and `V` are not types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two solutions:

- you may either initialize `F` out of the class
- or you may use pattern matching to extract the value

Example of [out of class initialization](http://ideone.com/fM2OJ):

```
template <typename DT, int DV, void (DT::*DF)(int)>
void (DT::* Description<DT, DV, DF>::F)(int) = DF;
```

*Sorry for this reading really bad, function types are never pretty :x*

Example of [pattern matching:](http://ideone.com/bgXwf)

```
// Make reading functions a bit easier
template <typename T> struct identity { typedef T type; };

template<typename DT, int DV, void (DT::*DF)(int)>
struct Description
{
    typedef DT T;                         // OK
    static const int V = DV;              // OK
};

template <typename DT, int DV, void (DT::*DF)(int)>
typename identity<void (DT::*)(int)>::type function(Description<DT, DV, DF>) {
  return DF;
}
```

In essence, you "deconstruct" the type during pattern matching. It requires a bit more writing that the in-class (static) member.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I shortened the second answer to just having a static member function in the description (static inline typename identity<void (DT::*)(int)>::type F() { return DF; }), so it can be called using D::F().  Looks like that's as good as it's going to get.

Comment: @Screndib: Ah nice, I had not thought about this combination, reads easy and no initialization issue! You can remove the `inline` here, it's unnecessary within a class (for info, it is only ever necessary for non-template functions/methods defined at namespace level).